# MATLAB GUI - How can I get programmatically whether an 'axis' object is empty or not?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have a MATLAB GUI, in which there is a figure (an 'axes' object).
I would like to know programmatically whetherthere is or not a plot in that figure/axes, because I would like to add an 'axis limit' control. The code would be:

```
if figure_is_empty
  axis([xMin xMax yMin yMax])
else
  'don t do anything, because there is nothing to resize'
end
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CurrentAxes` property of the `figure` object:

```
if ~isempty(get(gcf,'CurrentAxes'))
   axis([xMin xMax yMin yMax])
else
  % don't do anything, because there is nothing to resize'
end
```

See [Figure properties](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html) for more details.

Comment: You might want to replace `gcf` by the handle of your figure if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming h is the handle to the axis you want to check:

`~isempty(get(h,'Children'));`

'Children' contains the handles to graphics objects in the axes, so if you wanted to check more specifically (for example to differentiate between an image and a plot), you can return a list of what type of objects are present.  This will return empty if no child objects exist:

`get(get(h,'Children'),'Type')`

Comment: I have thought of doing this, but the problem is that `Children` include the axes and all the other UI stuff. Also, if the `HandleVisibility` property of the axis is set to `off`, it won't be listed:

"Children of the figure. A vector containing the handles of all axes, user-interface objects displayed within the figure. You can change the order of the handles and thereby change the stacking of the objects on the display.

When an object's HandleVisibility property is off, it is not listed in its parent's Children property. See HandleVisibility for more information."